# What is being declared in Dog copy constructor [:Mammal(rhs)]?

Tags: c++, oop, copy-constructor

While reading "Sams teach yourself c++ in 21 days" I cannot understand how does virtual copy constructor work. 
Full code from book is here:
[http://cboard.cprogramming.com/cplusplus-programming/9392-virtual-copy-constructor-help.html][1]

Especially virtual method  Clone() calls Mammal copy constructor and Dog copy constructor
because it returns "Mammal*" and  returns "new dog (*this)"

```
  Mammal::Mammal(const Mammal &rhs):itsAge(rhs.GetAge())
    {
    cout <<  "Mammal copy constructor\n";
    };

Dog::Dog (const Dog &rhs):Mammal(rhs) //what is ":Mammal(rhs)" here -     
                                      // call of Mammal copy constructor?  
                                      //if not why is it required?
                                      //or what is it here?
{
    cout << "Dog copy constructor\n";
};
```

And what does return "return new Dog(*this)"?
new object or pointer at new object?

Thank you for your answers.
P.S.
Sorry for my previous answer with wrong tags.
It is my first experience of using 'stackoverflow"

Comment: Please consider studying [a good textbook on C++](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/596781).

Comment: `new Dog(*this)` will create a copy of `*this` that is dynamically allocated and return the pointer to that copy.

Comment: If you really want to learn C++, stop reading and throw that book away right now and get a decent one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: This is an initialization list.  Please get a good book.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dog(*this);
```

creates an object of type Dog by calling the copy constructor. Since Dog derives from Mammal, the Mammal constructor is called. In particular, you can see from this code

```
Dog::Dog(const Dog & rhs):
Mammal(rhs)
```

that the copy constructor of Mammal gets called, which is passed rhs as a parameter.

```
new Dog(*this);
```

returns the pointer to a heap-allocated object of type Dog, which is initialized using the copy constructor (see above). When

```
virtual Mammal* Clone() { return new Dog(*this); }
```

gets called, the Dog* returned by the new operator gets converted to a Mammal* and returned.